# classNotFound Exception on glassfish server

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

I have created a simple java class and my server is glassfish server 4.0. I am getting Classnotfound exception on server start.
I am using java jdk1.7.0_60. My classpath is set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin and also my JAVA_HOME set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin.

Here is my java code

```
    package java.kabita;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import java.util.List;

    import javax.jws.WebService;

    @WebService
    public class ProductCatalog {



    public List<String> productCategories()
    {
        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        categories.add("Books");
        categories.add("Music");
        categories.add("Movies");
        return categories;
    }


    }
```

Here is the error

```
        Info: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (build 89)
    Info: Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
    Info: SEC1115: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
    Info: SEC1115: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
    Info: SEC1115: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
    Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 31ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8,080]
    Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8,181]
    Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4,848]
    Info: Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
    Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3,700]
    Info: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.web.glue, null) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.web.glue [263]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.web.javax.servlet.jsp, null) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.web.javax.servlet.jsp [149]], State = [READY]
    Info: visiting unvisited references
    Info: SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.
    Info: SEC1010: Entering Security Startup Service
    Info: SEC1143: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
    Info: SEC1011: Security Service(s) Started Successfully
    Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
    Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
    Info: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
    Info: Created virtual server server
    Info: Created virtual server __asadmin
    Info: Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
    Info: Virtual server server loaded default web module 
    Info: visiting unvisited references
    Info: visiting unvisited references
    Info: Loading application [Testmart] at [/Testmart]
    Info: Loading application Testmart done in 2,094 ms
    Info: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (89) startup time : Felix (2,094ms), startup services(2,937ms), total(5,031ms)
    Info: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
    Info: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-14 20:07:34...
    Info: JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://Lenovo-PC:8686/jndi/rmi://Lenovo-PC:8686/jmxrmi
    Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7,676]
    Info: Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@1811aeb as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@4af355.
    Info: visiting unvisited references
    Info: visiting unvisited references
    Info: Web service endpoint deployment events listener registered successfully.
    Info: visiting unvisited references
    Warning: AS-DEPLOYMENT-00012
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.kabita.ProductCatalog
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1761)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1611)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.impl.ModuleScanner.getElements(ModuleScanner.java:297)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:585)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:462)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:446)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:419)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:396)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:198)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:222)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:878)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:818)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:374)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common [48]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.hk2.hk2, 2.1.92) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2 [118]], State = [READY]
    Info: visiting unvisited references
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-plugin-service, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-plugin-service [58]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.deployment.deployment-client, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.deployment.deployment-client [67]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-api, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-api [230]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-impl, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-impl [231]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(javax.servlet-api, 3.1.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [javax.servlet-api [147]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(javax.servlet.jsp-api, 2.3.1) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [javax.servlet.jsp-api [148]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.el.javax.el, 3.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.el.javax.el [132]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.jsftemplating, 2.1.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.jsftemplating [186]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.dataprovider, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.dataprovider [63]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.pkg.client, 1.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.pkg.client [229]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jca-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jca-plugin [54]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-corba-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-corba-plugin [51]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-web-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-web-plugin [60]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-community-branding-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-community-branding-plugin [49]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jts-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jts-plugin [57]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-plugin [53]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common-full-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common-full-plugin [47]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-concurrent-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-concurrent-plugin [50]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common [48]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jms-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jms-plugin [56]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-cluster-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-cluster-plugin [46]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-lite-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-lite-plugin [52]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-updatecenter-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-updatecenter-plugin [59]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jdbc-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jdbc-plugin [55]], State = [READY]
    Warning: Unable to load class java.kabita.ProductCatalog, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.kabita.ProductCatalog
    Info: Loading application [Testmart] at [/Testmart]
    Info: Testmart was successfully deployed in 1,313 milliseconds.
    Info: visiting unvisited references
    Info: visiting unvisited references
    Info: visiting unvisited references
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common [48]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.hk2.hk2, 2.1.92) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2 [118]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-plugin-service, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-plugin-service [58]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.deployment.deployment-client, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.deployment.deployment-client [67]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-api, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-api [230]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-impl, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-impl [231]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(javax.servlet-api, 3.1.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [javax.servlet-api [147]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(javax.servlet.jsp-api, 2.3.1) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [javax.servlet.jsp-api [148]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.el.javax.el, 3.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.el.javax.el [132]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.jsftemplating, 2.1.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.jsftemplating [186]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.dataprovider, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.dataprovider [63]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.pkg.client, 1.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.pkg.client [229]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jca-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jca-plugin [54]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-corba-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-corba-plugin [51]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-web-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-web-plugin [60]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-community-branding-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-community-branding-plugin [49]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jts-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jts-plugin [57]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-plugin [53]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common-full-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common-full-plugin [47]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-concurrent-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-concurrent-plugin [50]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common [48]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jms-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jms-plugin [56]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-cluster-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-cluster-plugin [46]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-lite-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-lite-plugin [52]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-updatecenter-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-updatecenter-plugin [59]], State = [READY]
    Info: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jdbc-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jdbc-plugin [55]], State = [READY]
    Info: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-14 20:07:34...
    Info: Listening to REST requests at context: /management/domain.
    Info: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930) for context ''
    Info: Loading application [__admingui] at [/]
    Info: Loading application __admingui done in 8,375 ms
    Warning: Context path from ServletContext:  differs from path from bundle: /
    Info: Redirecting to /common/index.jsf
    Info: Admin Console: Initializing Session Attributes...
```

Comment: what is your java file name.? Both class name and file name should be same..

Comment: Both my class name and file name are ProductCatalog.